# How can I publish an app to the App Store with my client's developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-developer-account

I am a freelancer. I developed an iOS app for my client. She has an individual developer account, but we want me to upload an app to the App Store Connect because my client is actually not able to handle this, she even has no Mac. What we should do? She needs to share her account with me or what? My client gave me an Admin role in App Store Connect, but I cannot upload the app from Xcode to App Store Connect. We really need help. What should we do? Thank you in advance for your response! This is what I see when trying to upload archive from Xcode: [Error in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q0RE.png)

Comment: Do you have a developer account yourself?

Comment: keep looking in the account management page. you need a distribution certificate and a development certificate with your name. She has to do this on the Developer page (developer.apple.com).

Comment: @johnelemans So I am actually able to do all that things with only my client's developer account and my Apple ID' admin role? I don't have my own paid developer account

Comment: Yes, there are a few steps. As a I said you need to make the certificates and install them on your development computer.